# Taking a random sample from a non radom sample and checking it is unbiased

Tags: sampling, unbiased-estimator

I have a large population and I want select a sample based on some characteristics hence the selected sample is not random since  not all members of the population have an equal chance of being selected. From that **non-random sample**, I will pick a **random** **subset**. My question is that random subset unbiased and can get a consistent estimate from it? For example, can I prove that the mean of that subset converges to the mean of the non-random sample and the mean of population? Assuming **discrete and iid**. I liked at some posts like [This one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487295/what-if-a-non-random-sample-is-identical-to-a-random-sample), [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/471752/why-is-sample-mean-talked-about-when-the-sample-is-not-a-random-variable) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72049/how-to-deal-with-non-random-samples) but did not answer my questions.

**Another way:** What if I start with the random sample first and then non-random sample second? Will I get an consistent estimator and unbiased mean?

**Example :**

Suppose I am trying to find the mean of the even numbers of the populations. Then I have to pick a non-random sample of even numbers right? And then I take a random subset of that non-random sample to show that the mean of that subset is consistent estimator.

Comment: If the mean of your non-random sample is biased then the mean of a random sample from it will presumably also be a biased estimator of the population mean.   Similarly a non-random sample from a random sample may also be a biased estimator of the population mean.